# DotNetNuke 5.6.2 - What is the best method to incorporate the default DNN Forgot Password functionality into a custom module?

Tags: dotnetnuke

What is the best way to incorporate this default Forgot Password functionality into a custom module?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking the "Forgot Password" LinkButton redirects the user to SendPassword.ascx user control:

```
Response.Redirect(NavigateURL("SendPassword"), True)
```

You can do the same in your custom module, or roll up your own password reset form. In the latter case, I would take a copy of SendPassword.ascx as a template.